# restrict past dates in metro-ui datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-metro, datetimepicker

I'm using [metro-iu](https://metroui.org.ua/datepicker.html) `datetimpicker` in my project and I'm restricting paste dates using this code:

```
            <div class="cell size-p20 padding10">
                <label>Select Date: *</label>
                <div class="full-size">
                    <div class="input-control text" id="datepicker">
                        <input id="filter-date" type="text" ng-model="selectedDate"/>
                        <button class="button">
                            <span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button primary" ng-click="doAction()">
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the jquery which is preforming this restriction:

```
       $(function(){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                minDate: new Date()
            });
        });
```

Check this example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/30e371ou/) for this restriction, but as you can see it also restricts today date so you are not able to click on it and I don't want that, so how can I fix this, so it will restrict date from yesterday and not today, thanks.

Comment: May be try like this https://jsfiddle.net/30e371ou/2/

Comment: That did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the min date as yesterday manually Use date.now subtract the day by millisecond

```
$(function(){
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate:new Date(Date.now()-86400000)
   });
});
```

See this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/30e371ou/5/)